# ActiveMQ set properties with startup parameters

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there a way to set up some properties defined in activemq.xml (such as the shared storage) as startup parameters ?

```
<kahaDB directory="${data}/kahadb"/>
```

Running amq with -Dparam=value does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

I find it weird that this doesn't work for you, for example we are currently using the following Broker configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE" />
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
        <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:activemq.properties</value>
                <value>file:///${user.home}/activemq.properties</value>
                <value>file:///#{systemProperties['activemq.properties']}</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <broker useJmx="${activemq.expose.jmx}" persistent="false"
        brokerName="${activemq.brokerName}"
        xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">
        <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
                <policyEntries>
                    <policyEntry queue=">" enableAudit="false">
                        <networkBridgeFilterFactory>
                            <conditionalNetworkBridgeFilterFactory replayWhenNoConsumers="true"/>
                        </networkBridgeFilterFactory>
                    </policyEntry>
                </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
        <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage limit="${activemq.memoryUsage}" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="${activemq.tempUsage}" />
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
        <networkConnectors>
            <networkConnector
                name="queues"
                uri="static:(${activemq.otherBrokers})"
                networkTTL="3"
                decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                conduitSubscriptions="false" >
                <excludedDestinations>
                    <topic physicalName=">" />
                </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
            <networkConnector
                name="topics"
                uri="static:(${activemq.otherBrokers})"
                networkTTL="3"
                decreaseNetworkConsumerPriority="true"
                conduitSubscriptions="true" >
                <excludedDestinations>
                    <queue physicalName=">" />
                </excludedDestinations>
            </networkConnector>
        </networkConnectors>
        <transportConnectors>
            <!-- expose a TCP transport for clients to use -->
            <transportConnector
                uri="${activemq.protocol}${activemq.host}:${activemq.tcp.port}"
                updateClusterClients="true"
                rebalanceClusterClients="true" />
            <transportConnector
                uri="${activemq.websocket.protocol}${activemq.websocket.host}:${activemq.websocket.port}"
                updateClusterClients="true"
                rebalanceClusterClients="true" />
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

Here normally the properties are read from the given properties file, however I have often used direct -D JMV system properties to overrule those from the properties file for some tests and never encountered any issues. I guess you could try the slighly more complex syntax of #{systemProperties['property.name']} to specifically set that a given property is a system property and not from a placeholder.

One last Point: which version of ActiveMQ are you using and which version of spring is this version using? I think the whole placeholder syntax was added somewhere around spring 3.1, so really quite some time ago, but this is the only reason I could imagine why this isn't working for you.